# Can textInteractionFlags be set on all QLabels globally?

Tags: qt

How can I make all QLabels in an application mouse selectable (Qt::TextSelectableByMouse) by default?

It's not just my labels I'm interested in, but also, for exanple, the one used in QInputDialog which is not selectable while the one in QMessageBox is selectable.

Comment: You could subclass the widgets and have just constructor which sets the right flags etc.

Comment: But I want _ALL_ QLabels to have this property, not just the ones I create.

Comment: If you can't for example do a search-replace and change every `new QLabel` to a subclass and promote any labels in `.ui` forms (note, you don't have to change pointer types, because it is subclass), then the only solution I can think of is in Pavel's answer. Well, you can also compile custom version of Qt with this small change in some widgets..

Comment: @hyde: You're right. I think the only solution other than Pavel's is to patch Qt to set that property by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QApplication::topLevelWidgets` to find all windows and `widget->findChildren<QLabel*>()` to find all labels in a window. Then you can set appropriate flags for each label. You need to call this function periodically but not too often (`findChildren` can be slow). Maybe you can connect to `QApplication::focusChanged` signal, detect when new top level window is created and do the check for this window.

Comment: I'm not keen on this solution, but it might be useful in limited circumstances and possibly in a debug mode to ensure that all QLabels have been set properly.